# Set global timeOut values for REST api calls from PHP clients

Tags: php, linux, apache, rest, curl

I am using php curl (libcurl) to call REST APIs. But the issue is ,i need to give timeout for every REST api call.

can i set a global timeout for the curl calls generated from php client ? I researched a lot but all over the internet i can see that this is not possible with libcurl,so if that is the case then please suggest me some other library which can do this in php or any possibility on linux/apache level ?

Comment: you could set a global variable and use that in the curl request ( in each request ) ~ `$GLOBALS['CURL_TIMEOUT']=10;` ??

Comment: @RamRaider thanks but i don't want to do that. If someone misses this part then their curl will keep on running infinite.